# Select write time of collection column cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli, cqlsh

How to select `WRITETIME`of a column of type `list<text>` in Cassandra. I get the following exception when I try this `SELECT WRITETIME (column_name) from TABLE_NAME WHERE ID='1';`
Exception  `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot use selection function writeTime on collections`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a way to get the writetime of the values in a collection column.